# Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

trying to read between StackOverflow and the documentation of meteor-simple-schema but can't find a solution. I'trying to insert data in the Meteor.users collection through a form. But keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator
```

> checkModifier 
>   @ simple-schema-validation.js:271doValidation1 @ simple-schema-validation.js:321doValidation @ simple-schema-context.js:9simpleSchemaValidationContextValidate @ simple-schema-context.js:44doValidate @ collection2.js:317_.each.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) @ collection2.js:154(anonymous function) @ VM47084:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM47083:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM47083:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM47083:682

Any clue?

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.artistform.events({

    'submit': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
        var currentUserId = this.userId;
        form={firstName:firstname.value, lastName:lastname.value};
        Meteor.users.update({_id:currentUserId}, {$set:form});

    }
 });
}
```

And the Schema

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserCountry = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
},
code: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[A-Z]{2}$/,
    optional:true
}
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
firstName: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/,
    optional: true
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
    optional: true
},
birthday: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true
},
category : {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['Painting', 'Music','Other'],
    optional: true
},
 website: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
    optional: true
 },
 bio: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
 },
country: {
    type: Schema.UserCountry,
    optional: true
}
```

});

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
email: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
},
"email.verified": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
},
profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return new Date();
        } else if (this.isUpsert) {
            return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
        } else {
            this.unset();
        }
    }
}
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: when do you get that error? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I think is related to simple-schema, I'm missing something in the configuration. When I run the form without the Schema section, works fine.

Comment: @eliosolutions, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397314/meteor-collections-schema-not-allowing-google-authentication.  Try adding "services: {type: Object,blackbox: true}" to your Schema.User definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this schema

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
  email: {
    type: Object
  },
  'email.address': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  "email.verified": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
      } else {
        this.unset();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Btw if you are using account-password then this schema won't work as that package expect emails to be stored in a certain way.